# Unable to upload multiple image to server Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I tried too many time and used many way but could not upload image to server let me know what I am doing wrong,but unable to upload image to server.

```
func callsendImageAPI(){
        
        let headers: HTTPHeaders
        headers = ["Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
                   "Accept-Language": ApiService.instance.defaults[.langugaeCode] ?? "en",
                   "Authorization": "Bearer " + ApiService.instance.getToken()
        ]
        let url = BASE_URL + "uploadImages"
        AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            for item in self.carImages.enumerated() {
                switch item.element  {
                case .photo(let photo):
                    let image = photo.image
                    multipartFormData.append(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!, withName: "images[0]", fileName: "file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
            
            
        },to: url, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(),
        method: .post,
        headers: headers).response{ response in
            
            if((response.error != nil)){
                do{
                    if let jsonData = response.data{
                        
                        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let JSON = try jsonDecoder.decode([RegularPostImage].self, from: jsonData)
                        print(JSON)
                    }
                }catch{
                    print("error message")
                }
            }else{
                print(response.error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code the was issue was due to server validation.